# PHP Mysql : I have a problem combining 1 variable that has different values

Tags: php, database, group-by, distinct, group-concat

| column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| id 1 | 10 |
| id 1 | 30 |
| id 2 | 20 |
| id 2 | 50 |

and i want that column 1 just show one variable like

| column 1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| id 1 | 10 |
|  | 30 |
| id 2 | 20 |
|  | 50 |

Comment: I'm not completely understanding your question, do you want to combine the values in column 2 that have the same value in column 1? So in your example should the column 2 in your output just be 40?

Comment: Can you please be a little more informative, I don't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Jocohan , i just want combine that column 1

Comment: @Codestrip , that i want is just that column 1 be combine like id1 value = 10 , 30 . id2 : 40,50 that column 1 just show 1 variable